# Pass a template function with their template argument as an argument of another function in C++

Tags: c++

I have a project, in there I have to pass a function and their template argument as an argument of another function. Do you guy know how to do it.

I would like to add more detail about my code:

```
template <typename T, typename functional>
void implement(int ind, Element<T> *ele, functional f) {

f(&ele[ind]);
return;
}
template <typename T>
void INIT_ADV_1D(Element<T> *ele) {

    Vect1D<T> *PHI = &ele->U[1];
    Vect1D<T> *U = &ele->U[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < ele->order + 1; i++) {
        U[i] = 1.e0;
        if (ele->xk(i) <= 0.5e0)
            PHI[0](i) = 1.e0;
        else
            PHI[0](i) = 0.e0;
    }
}
main (){
implement(0, model.Ele, INIT_ADV_1D);
}
```

I already searched in our forum about this topic, but They just guide to make a function as an argument of other function which not suite my target.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not clear. However, one statement can be made which is universally true. Any kind of a "template argument" must be a compile-time constant, because that's what a template is. Passing, in some form of fashion, something at runtime that somehow must be turned into a template argument cannot be done in C++. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: Why do you require ele to be a pointer? This doesn't really make sense. What if I want to pass it a `std::vector` instead? Also, instead of using `functional`, why not just use `std::function` instead?

Comment: Because, The ele is an array, that the functional f will handle ele[ind]

Comment: INIT_ADV_1D is a name of a template. You can't pass it to anything.

Comment: rustyx, So what should I chance in this code?

Comment: You need to specify the type. `INIT_ADV_1D<decltype(model.Ele)>`

Comment: rustyx, Thank you so much, Based on your advise, with a little bit modification the code is run. Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

While the question is quite unclear, I think that something like this is needed:

```
  template<typename types, typename functional> implement(types &data, functional f)
  {
     ... 
  }

  main()
  {
       implement(data, [](const data &d) { ...});
  }
```

If you want to limit  the types of  function to have a specific signature, use std::function from the functional header instead of the type functional. Hope this helps to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

In your code,  f is not called with a pointer. Change to

```
f(&ele[ind])
```

Does this solve the problem?